# Unable to create a Google BigQuery materialized view with a specific partition DAY

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a simple Google BigQuery table which is partitioned by DAY.

```
TABLE
-----
created_on TIMESTAMP REQUIRED,  -- These will ALWAYS be UTC.
name STRING REQUIRED,
...
```

[image]

Now, I'm trying to make a MATERIALIZED VIEW from this table. Part of my code is wanting to create a PARTITION on this M.V. Only problem is, is that I need to change the value of how this M.V. is partitioned. Instead of the `created_on` TIMESTAMP (which all are UTC), I wish to make it 'Australia/Melbourne' (or whatever).

This M.V. will still be partitioned a TIMESTAMP into DAY's. It's just that the value is converted, before the partitioning.

I just can't see how to do this?

When I try permutations of the following, I keep getting errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW `materialized_views.prod_some_view`
  PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(created_on), "Australia/Melbourne"), DAY)
  CLUSTER BY event_name, office_id_hash, listing_id_hash
  OPTIONS (enable_refresh = true, refresh_interval_minutes = 5)
AS
WITH 
  <snipped>
```

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: Hi @Pure.Krome, Can you try this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#partition_expression) and [document2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) , hopefully it will help you.